# Combo boxes and union queries

Tags: sql, forms, combobox, union, ms-access-2013

Ok, so I have this part of my DB to keep track of the HDDs installed in our computers. Thing is, they're linked to either a 'Desktops' table if they're installed in a desktop PC or to a 'Laptops' table if they're in a Laptop. Little more or less like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPK4g.png)

I need to show certain HDDs in a HDD lookup form and allow the user to edit its fields. So my first guess was the following:

```
SELECT HDDs.* 
FROM Desktops INNER JOIN (HDDs INNER JOIN HDDmodels ON HDDs.Model=HDDmodels.Id) ON Desktops.SerialNum=HDDs.InPC
WHERE Criteria
UNION
SELECT HDDs.* 
FROM Laptops INNER JOIN (HDDs INNER JOIN HDDmodels ON HDDs.Model=HDDmodels.Id) ON Laptops.SerialNum=HDDs.InLaptop
WHERE Criteria
```

While this works for search purposes, the InPC, InLaptop and Model comboboxes turn to textfields in the results form when I include a Union in the query. Furthermore, those textfields show the PK of the linked table instead of the linked field and they're not editable. Without doing a Union query both parts of the above query work flawlessly.

So my question is, is there any way to do a Union query and still get comboboxes in the resulting datasheet form? Or do I have any way to avoid the Union query? Can't seem to find a way to nest join all the tables together otherways, specially since the above is a simplified schema and I actually need to join some other tables for criteria purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: Mrege your two tables into one, having _machine type_ as a foreign key to a (new) _machine type_ table.

Comment: Thx Gustav! I was considering doing that, but I wanted to tinker as little as possible with the structure the database had when I started working of it because that would require an insane amount of work to change many queries the DB already had and some others I have added following the current table structure. I'm guessing there's no other way to make combo boxes work with a union query?

Comment: I don't think so. If the data don't change that much, you could copy the two tables to one (temporary) table and use that for the combobox.

Comment: Ok so I did a little test to check if it worked (without changing the many edit queries) merging the two tables into a main 'computers' one with two subtables (desktops and laptops) with a 1-1 relation with a bit of data and linked to the corresponding models table. Now hard disk drives are tied to the computers table and there's no union in the query. Well, for some reason the query without the union now has the same behaviour as the query with the union did, both the HDD model and the computer comboboxes on the hdds table turn to text fields on the forms.I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: Can't tell without further info. However, SO is a code helper forum, so you may get better respons on a forum where you can post files - like _Experts Exchange_ or _UtterAccess_.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers Gustav. I finally got it to work with the joint table, not having to use the union. I had to rebuild the whole form and subform for it to show the comboboxes properly but now it's working great!